# Amazon Workdocs, user and password

Tags: api, authentication, amazon-workdocs

in my understanding, using the boto3 library to access the Workdocs API requires an authentication token, however, I have a user and password, which allows me to access the workdoc web interface.
Is there a way to get an authentication token using the user and password for WebUI?